# How to remove disabled, active class from bootstrap datepiker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, usability, bootstrap-datepicker

I have used [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), i included `return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : ''` in `onRender` function to disable past dates the problem is when i select previous year of any month it shows active, how to disable active class if disabled exist[image]

Answer (score 0):

comment this active function in your js.

```
   if (prevMonth.valueOf() === currentDate) {
            clsName += ' active';
   }
```

Like This

```
   // if (prevMonth.valueOf() === currentDate) {
   //         clsName += ' active';
   // }
```

--------------- Month Disabled - comment this active function ------------

```
  // if (currentYear === year) {
  //         months.eq(this.date.getMonth()).addClass('active');
  // }
```

--------------- Year Disabled - just remove active class in this code ------------

```
html += '<span class="year'+(i === -1 || i === 10 ? ' old' : '')+(currentYear === year ? ' ' : '')+'">'+year+'</span>';
```

This is My Screenshort

[image]

Comment: There is no code like `cls.push('active');` in bootstrap-datepicker.js

Comment: Not works,only the date highlighter is not present still date exist

Comment: I have put this my Screenshort

Comment: Select month and then choose previous month [attached_screenshot](http://s7.postimg.org/lkkies9sr/active_disabled.png)